# Как реализовать необычный алгоритм деления массива char на чистом Си?

Tags: c, массивы, char

Буду благодарен за помощь в реализации алгоритма.
Есть текст 256 символов, состоящий из латинских букв и пробелов, представленный массивом char A[256].
На выходе необходимо получить двумерный массив char B[10][20] (десять строк по 20 символов).
Сложность заключается в том, что нельзя "обрезать" строку на слове. Если последующее
слово выходит за границу строки (20 символов), его необходимо перенести в следующую строку. 
Новая строка не может начинаться с пробела.

Для наглядности приведу пример. На входе имеем текст:

"I follow the Moskva down to Gorky Park listening to the wind of change 
An August summer night Soldiers passing by Listening to the wind of change 
The world is closing in Did you ever think That we could be so close 
like brothers The futures in the air I ca"

На выходе:

Строка 1: "I follow the Moskva "

Строка 2: "down to Gorky Park  "

Строка 3: "listening to the    "

Строка 4: "wind of change An   "

Строка 5: "An August summer    "

Строка 6: "Soldiers passing by "

Строка 7: "Listening to the    "

Строка 8: "wind of change The  "

Строка 9: "The world is closing"

Строка 10: "in Did you ever     "

Каждая строка из 20 символов, если слово не влезает в конец строки, то вместо него последние ячейки массива заполняются пробелами.

Comment: Ну а в чем сложность? Готовите массив, смотрите, где нужно обрезать, и молитесь, чтоб не было слова длиной 21 символ...

Comment: заводите 2 переменные: позицию начала текущей подстроки и позицию последнего встреченного пробела. Идете по строке, если видите пробел, запоминаете его позицию во второй переменной. Если от начала подстроки до текущего символа стало 20 символов, то если текущий символ пробел - вот ваша строка целиком. Если там не пробел - то ваша строка от адреса в первой переменной до второй. Переставляете адрес начала подстроки на следующий символ после окончания найденной

Answer (score 0):

У вас пятая строка должна начинаться с August, кстати.

Вот:

```
char A[] =
    "I follow the Moskva down to Gorky Park listening to the wind of change "
    "An August summer night Soldiers passing by Listening to the wind of "
    "change The world is closing in Did you ever think That we could be so "
    "close like brothers The futures in the air I ca";

int main() {
    char B[10][20];

    for (int b = 0, beg = 0, end = beg + 20; b < 10 &&
            end < strlen(A); ++b) {
        while (A[end] != ' ') --end;

        strncpy(B[b], A + beg, end - beg);
        B[b][end - beg] = 0;
        beg = end + 1;
        end = beg + 20;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf("String %d: %s\n", i, B[i]);
    }
```